# What practices can help me hitchhike safely?

Tags: safety, hitchhiking

I would like to travel across Europe hitchhiking (me and my girlfriend). What should we do to make sure that we both lower chances of unpleasant meetings, and higher chances of succeeding?

Comment: Hitchhiking customs are very different between the European countries.

Comment: @RoboKaren I can't see how you could consider your comment even remotely helpful.

Comment: Avoid Calais, Southern Austria, Eastern Greece, South Western Spain,

Comment: Have you read everything in the excellent [HitchWiki](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Main_Page) yet?

Comment: This is an incredibly broad, open-ended question. There's really no way we can answer it here. But as Klaster suggested, the HitchWiki is likely to be of great help to you.  We just aren't the proper resource for this type of question.